# Running and managing NSTimer in different NSThread/NSRunLoop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, multithreading, nstimer, nsrunloop

I'm writing a Cocoa application, with a GUI designed in Interface Builder. I need to schedule background activity (at regular intervals) without blocking the UI, so I run it in a separate thread, like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(schedule) withObject:nil];
}

- (void) schedule {
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

    timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:FEED_UPDATE_INTERVAL
                                                  target:activityObj
                                        selector:@selector(run:)
                                        userInfo:nil
                                         repeats:YES]
         retain];

    [runLoop run];
    [pool release];
}
```

I retain the timer, so I can easily invalidate and reschedule.

Problem: I must also fire the run: method in response to GUI events, so it is synchronous (i.e. a "perform activity" button). Like this:

```
[timer fire];
```

I could do this with performSelectorInBackground too, and of course it doesn't block the UI. But this synchronous firings run in another runloop! So I have no guarantee that they won't overlap. How can I queue all of my firings on the same runloop?

Answer (score 0):

```
[timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantPast]];
```

I obtained the desired effect by adjusting the next fire date to be ASAP, by passing a past date to setFireDate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a classic solution for concurrency: semaphore. In your case, the easiest way is to use `@synchronized` directive. Surround the entire body (or at least, the sensitive part) of `run:` method with `@synchronized`. For the synchronization object I suggest you to use a specific ivar or static variable instead of the activityObj's class in order to avoid deadlocks.

```
-(void)run:(id)param {
    // do thread-safe things here
    @synchronized(syncObj) {
        // put your critical section here
    }
    // do more thread-safe things here
}
```

Code in critical section won't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

you should schedule NSTimer on mainThread (and fire the timer to perform the selector --- the selector can be execute on background thread, thus do not block UI), rather than schedule NSTimer on a background thread via GCD, because NSTimer will be added to a NSRunLoop, and every NSRunLoop is associated with a NSTread. So when using GCD, use dispatch_after instead of NSTimer to delay the things to happen.